# Remove redundant tags '<p><br></p>' in php?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, summernote

Removing redundant tags `<p><br></p>` at the beginning and end of the string, and in the middle leaving only one.

Input:

```
<p><br></p><p><br></p><p><br></p><p>gfdsgfdsgfds</p><p><br></p><p><br></p><p><br></p><p>gfdsgfdsgfdsgfds</p><p><br></p><p><br></p><p><br></p>
```

Desired output:

```
<p>gfdsgfdsgfds</p><p><br></p><p>gfdsgfdsgfdsgfds</p>
```

Alternative desired output:

```
<p>gfdsgfdsgfds</p><p><br></p><p><br></p><p><br></p><p>gfdsgfdsgfdsgfds</p>
```

I've tried to use: `preg_replace`

```
$string = preg_replace('/(<p><br></p>)+/', '', $string);
```

But the result is null.

Comment: My first question would be, why do you have such redundant tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **escape the slash `/` character** in your regex:

```
$string = preg_replace('/(<p><br><\/p>)+/', '', $string);
```

Also note that this **will remove all instances** where multiple of these patterns occor, resulting in the following:

```
<p>gfdsgfdsgfds</p><p>gfdsgfdsgfdsgfds</p>
```

To remove duplicates but leave one instance, could do the following:

```
$string = preg_replace('/(<p><br><\/p>)+/', '<p><br></p>', $string);
```

Comment: Capturing group is your friend, use a backreference: `$string = preg_replace('/(<p><br><\/p>)+/', '$1', $string);`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Purifier http://htmlpurifier.org/ can help you. It can clean up html code and also remove javascript for example if needed.